# Is this the correct formula for this quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I'm doing some excersises, but i'm not sure who to apply the 'formula' given:

$$x^2 - 2px + p^2 - 1 = 0$$.

I've found this formula on my book:

[image]

Is it the correct 'formula'?

If it were something like:

$$x^2 -2x + 9 - 1 = 0$$ i would make it, but the "p" confuses me. Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quadratic formula will work fine if you apply it and simplify. However in this case you might like to use the idea that any quadratic is of the form $$x^2-(\text{sum of roots})x+(\text{product of roots})=0$$
In this case the product of roots is $(p+1)(p-1)$

Comment: Yes, with this form I find it easier.

Answer (score 5):

Comparing $$a x^2 + b x + c =0$$
with
$$x^2 - 2p \, x + p^2 - 1 = 0$$

you should see that, in your case,  $a=1$, $b=-2p$ and $c= p^2-1$

Comment: Thanks, i see it. I can move forward from here.

Answer (score 4):

$$ \left[x^2 - 2px + p^2\right] - 1 = 0 \\
(x - p)^2 - (1)^2 = 0 \\
\left[(x - p) - 1)\right]\left[(x - p) + 1\right] = 0$$

Giving you $ x = p \pm 1 $

Comment: Since when does a "hint" include the full answer?

Answer (score 1):

That is the right formula,  you just set your coefficients appropriately.   So $a=1$,  $b=-2p$, and $c=p^2-1$.  Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Thanks, i see it. I can move forward from here